# How to retrieve the value from QuietlyCoding's NumberPicker?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a button which on click must generate a dialog box containing a number picker, and ok-cancel buttons. I am working on Android 2.3.3 (not API 11), so I have downloaded the number picker from **[here](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5)**. It is working fine. I need to get the count entered in the number picker after OK button is clicked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is not really a StackOverflow question. It's not a standard control, and is really a question you should be asking the control author. [SO isn't a substitute for vendor technical support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/172661). The site you linked also mentions a demo app - did you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom dialog...

Create the layout in XML, called picker_dialog.xml ie:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <com.mypackage.NumberPicker
         //set your layout
         />
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
         <Button
              //cancel button
              />
         <Button
              //Ok button
              />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create your Custom Dialog class

```
public class DialogPicker extends Picker {

    public DialogPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.picker_dialog);
        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.my_number_picker);
        //do whatever
        Button okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_ok_button);
        //set your click listener
    }
}
```

In your activity, just run:

```
PickerDialog pd = new PickerDialog(this);
pd.show();
```

Good luck

Comment: There is an error coming up in

PickerDialog pd = new PickerDialog(this);

it says :

The constructor PickerDialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined.

This is the only error I am getting. Please help.

Comment: You should be passing the context, not the listener, ie, pass MyActivity.this instead of the "this" pointing to you click listener.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an android:id value to your NumberPicker element in your layout
   XML.
2. When you inflate the layout for your AlertDialog, call
   findViewById() on the inflated layout, passing in the ID you
   supplied in step #1, and casting the result to be a NumberPicker.
3. In the demo there is a NumberPicker class that correspond to your number picker widget, this class contains a getCurrent() method use it to retrieve the current value of the number picker.

Answer (score 0):

try this class

public class DialogPicker extends Picker {

```
public DialogPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.picker_dialog);
    NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.my_number_picker);
    //do whatever
    Button okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_ok_button);
    //set your click listener
}
```

}